# Encoder-Decoder LSTM model gives 'nan' loss and predictions

Tags: python, keras, lstm, chatbot, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to create a basic encoder-decoder model for training a chatbot. X contains the questions or human dialogues and Y contains the bot answers. I have padded the sequences to the max size of input and output sentences. X.shape = (2363, 242, 1) and Y.shape = (2363, 144, 1). But during training, **the loss has value 'nan' for all epochs and the prediction gives array with all values as 'nan'**. I have tried using 'rmsprop' optimizer instead of 'adam'. I cannot use loss function 'categorical_crossentropy' as the output is not one-hot encoded but a sequence. What exactly is wrong with my code?

**Model**

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=64, activation='relu', input_shape=(X.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(RepeatVector(Y.shape[1]))
model.add(LSTM(units=64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=1)))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

hist = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=20, batch_size=64, verbose=2)
model.save('encoder_decoder_model_epochs20.h5')
```

**Data Preparation**

```py
def remove_punctuation(s):
    s = s.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
    s = s.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    return s

def prepare_data(fname):
    word2idx = {'PAD': 0}
    curr_idx = 1
    sents = list()
    for line in open(fname):
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            tokens = remove_punctuation(line.lower()).split()
            tmp = []
            for t in tokens:
                if t not in word2idx:
                    word2idx[t] = curr_idx
                    curr_idx += 1
                tmp.append(word2idx[t])
            sents.append(tmp)
    sents = np.array(pad_sequences(sents, padding='post'))
    return sents, word2idx

human = 'rdany-conversations/human_text.txt'
robot = 'rdany-conversations/robot_text.txt'

X, input_vocab = prepare_data(human)
Y, output_vocab = prepare_data(robot)

X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1))
Y = Y.reshape((Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1], 1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check that you do not have any NaNs in your input. If this is not the case it might be *exploding gradients*. Standardize your inputs (MinMax- or Z-scaling), try smaller learning rates, clip  the gradients, try a different weight initialization scheme.

Comment: Thanks alot. Seems it was due to exploding gradients. Min-max normalization worked for me.